# How do I push elements to an existing array in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I generate trigram snippets as primary keys. The field `words` is an array of terms represented by the trigram key, e.g.:

```
{
    "trigram": "#ha",
    "words": ["hahaha", "harley", "mahalo"]
}
```

The problem is pushing new terms to the array. I don't know how to use `$addToSet` for this.

```
db["Terms"].update({
  "trigram": trigram,
  {"$addToSet": {"words":word}
})
```

It should append `word` to the `words` field. But the database remains empty without returning any error messages.

What should I do?

Comment: Is it working: `db["Terms"].update({ "trigram":"#ha", {"$addToSet":{"words":word} })`?

Comment: It is working in the sense that it does not yield error messages. But it does not do what I want... (it does nothing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you use the `upsert` option, an `update` will only modify existing docs, not create them.  Try this instead:

```
db["Terms"].update(
  { "trigram":trigram }, 
  { "$addToSet":{"words":word} }, 
  upsert=True)
```

By using the `upsert` option, it will create the doc if missing, otherwise just update the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

try this `db["Terms"].update({ "trigram": "#ha"}, {"$addToSet": {"words":"word"} })`

remember you need update, so need separe **find** `{ "trigram": "#ha"}`, **update** `{"$addToSet": {"words":"word"} }`  and add words in `" "`.